# Power supply for Asus tinker board

Tags: single-board

I am thinking of getting an Asus tinker board to experiment with it. Particularly with overclocking it.

My question is, with regards to power supply. I understand that a tinker board draws about 5V/2.4A to work. But if I intend to overclock it, will this be sufficient? Or do I need to get a 5V/3A power supply instead?

Suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Better to go big, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: But I wouldn't want to fry the board. Will 3A fry the board?

Comment: No, that's not how power supplies work. All the additional amperage is doing is adding capacity for the device to draw more current if it's required. If your device idles at 500mAH, it'll draw 500mAH from the power supply. If it needs 3A and your PSU only allows up to 2.5A then your device will likely shut down (my Raspberry Pi used to do this with a 1.5A charger when I started drawing too much current)

Comment: I see. So it's fine if I use a USB power hub that can output 5V/3A because if the tinker board doesn't need that much power, it will not draw the full 3A. But if it does need it when I overclock, then it'll work out fine. Yes?

Comment: Correctamundo dude!